# Vaadin 8: error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.vaadin.ui.MenuBar.addItem with GridContextMenu 3

Tags: java, widget, vaadin, vaadin8

I am trying to make the  Vaadin plugin GridContextMenu work on my project. I am using version 8.7.1 of Vaadin, recently migrated from an earlier version 7.
I first used version 2 of the context menu but did not get any visible results. So I tried to take the latest version. I now get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.vaadin.ui.MenuBar.addItem (Ljava / lang / String;) Lcom / vaadin / ui / MenuBar $ MenuItem;
```

I tried to clean the caches of Maven and my IntelliJ, my local .m2
and recompile my widgetset etc... But I always get the same error.

Here is the line of code causing the problem :

`GridContextMenu<VehiculeImmat> gridContextMenu=new GridContextMenu<>(this);`

Has anyone ever gotten that problem or an idea of ​​how to solve it?

Comment: Are you executing this line in a Class that extends `Grid<VehiculeImmat>`?

Comment: What is your Vaadin version? If I recall correctly, there were breaking changes in 8.6 for MenuBar. So if your version is >=`8.6`, then `3.0.0` add-on should work fine, otherwise, you should try to use `2.1.0` version of ContextMenu

Comment: my version of vaadin is 8.71 but I use dependency of migration "vaadin-compatibility".
I am using this object in a class that extends a generic custom grid that extends Grid

Answer (score 1):

Hy,
This is causing due to API version mismatch as **GridContextMenu** is moved to package **com.vaadin.v7.contextmenu** so try to change import package. 
ContextMenu v3.0 is rewritten so they have changed some package hierarchy but it compatible with Vaadin7 and 8.

Further see API doc and release notes on following link
https://vaadin.com/directory/component/vaadin-contextmenu/api

Comment: What solution can I put in place to correct this problem?
I am forced to keep these compatibility packages.
I do not understand the origin of the conflict, this package com.vaadin.v7.contextmenu it was not just created to avoid conflicts?